# Java web service - framework for parsing response text

Tags: java, web-services, http, jakarta-ee, httpwebrequest

I am writing a java application which invokes a web service and uses its response text.
(i.e.) it invokes a URL like `http://web-server.com/item/3455`

That URL would return a response text (string) like "nexus".

For implementing the above functionality, is there any readily available framework that we can make use of? Or should I code the functionality from scratch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the API is not strictly RESTful, you can use spring-web's [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) like so:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://web-server.com/item/3455", String.class);
```

Comment: thanks. that looks really cool, I am just wondering if there could be a lighter option (a smaller framework).

Comment: Could you provide the maven dependency for this jar? many thanks.

Comment: If you're using Maven, it's in the central repo (http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|spring-web).

Comment: The lightest option per my experience is to use apache http client to make a request and capture response, and dont bother whether its webservice/restful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Based on url, it seems you are doing REST call. You may use [HTTPURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) API.

Comment: thanks. Could we use this for non-rest web services as well? For example, if the URL is like http://web-server.com/item?id=3455

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a simple HTTP client to do what you're talking about. The [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) project from Apache is a popular choice and would certainly work for what you're trying to do.